# cPanel Themes and shared hosting

Tags: php, themes, cpanel, shared-hosting

I'm with HostPapa and I submitted a ticket to change my cPanel theme to the new paper lantern. They replied saying it's not possible to change the theme in a shared hosting environment. I also enquired about changing to PHP5.5 instead of 5.4. Same response. I was just wondering if this is true?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depend on how their shared hosting service is structurated. There are companies that allow custoumers to change their php version with a custom php.ini file in their directory and change the cPanel theme just for them. Otherwise, it's possible that in a shared hosting environment, the company can't perform customizations for each user due to a different shared hosting structure.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I just have 1 more tiny question, the server currently has PHP 5.4.41, should they have upgraded to 5.4.45 or even 5.5 by now?

Comment: Usually they wait for an upgrade of PHP because there may be incompatibilities between new versions of PHP and some of their systems. For example PHP 5.5 is not supported yet by ioncube (last time I checked) that is a must for some applications.